# How to sum cumulative costs across price ranges for a given quantity?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a table that looks like this:

| Quantity | Price (Per Item) |
| --- | --- |
| 10000 or less | $50 |
| 10001 - 15000 | $40 |
| 15001 - 30000 | $30 |
| 30000 or more | $20 |

So for example, if I order quantity 16000, the total price will consist of:

1. $50 for the first 10000 items ($500000)
2. $40 for the next 5000 items ($200000)
3. $30 for the last 1000 items ($30000)

Hence, total price will be $730000 (cost is cumulative based on various price ranges for a given quantity).

I am trying to code a Python function that takes in quantity as a parameter and returns the overall price. I am able to do it by hardcoding the quantity ranges, using multiple if else conditions and doing some basic math, but was wondering if there is an optimal way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether the following is optimal, but you can try something like the following:

```py
def get_price(quantity):
    p_schedule = [(10000, 50), (5000, 40), (15000, 30), (None, 20)]
    price = 0
    while quantity: # while we still have quantity to exhaust
        q, p = p_schedule.pop(0) # get current price schedule bracket
        # q_now: quantity to exhaust in the current bracket.
        # if q == None, then use all the remaining quantity.
        q_now = min(q, quantity) if q else quantity
        price += p * q_now # add to the price
        quantity -= q_now # subtract the quantity used in this bracket
    return(price)

print(get_price(16000)) # 730000
```